# Jest test fails due to mock function despite its execution

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

The following Jest unit test:

```
const onSuccess = jest.fn(() => console.log("Boooboooo"));
render(
  <Footer onSuccess={onSuccess}
  />
);
const approveButton = screen.getByRole("button", {name: "APPROVE"});
userEvent.click(approveButton);
expect(onSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

fails:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

whereas `onSuccess` does run:

```
console.log
Boooboooo
```

The last two parts are from Jest logs. Any idea what's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `onSuccess` function be called asynchronous, this means the assertion function is called before `onSuccess` function is called.

Let’s try to use [waitFor](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/) helper to assert the callback function is called:

```
userEvent.click(approveButton);
await waitFor(() => expect(onSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled());
```